# How to avoid refreshing of masterpage while navigating in site?

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

In my website, I have created a masterpage and attached all of my pages to it.
My masterpage structure contains a header and a footer. On the left it has a treeview control, which i have attached to all my pages, and on the right there is a contentplaceholder to show the content of respective pages.

My problem is that when I click any link in the treeview it refreshes the whole masterpage and open the respective page. I wish to avoid this refresh. Means it should show the contents of page on right side contentplaceholder without refreshing the whole page.

I have seen people suggesting to use iframes. But for using iframes I shall have to restructure my website. Is there any other solution than iframes and with minimal changes to the work that I have done?

Comment: Did you Get the Solution to this Question?? If Yes Can you tell me???

Answer (score 3):

You will probably want to look at using AJAX to stop this from happening.  You will want to read up on using an [UpdatePanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.updatepanel.aspx).  Below are some good articles that goes over this:

- http://geekswithblogs.net/ranganh/archive/2007/05/11/112405.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399001.aspx

You also have the option of using jQuery to handle your AJAX calls.  While I typically prefer the use of jQuery when using AJAX, I am not sure I would use it in your situation.  If you would like to look at what it offers take a look at these links:

- http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/
- http://sixrevisions.com/javascript/the-power-of-jquery-with-ajax/

Comment: Hi Abe
Thanks for your reply.
I am asking about moving between one page to another in my website by clicking on the links in treeview, i want to stop refreshing of masterpage there.
While for retrieving data within my page, i am already using ajax there.
Can i use ajax to stop refreshing on masterpage while moving from one page to another?

Answer (score 0):

You could put the content you wish to change inside an `asp:UpdatePanel` that way that will be the only thing that is repainted (it uses AJAX under the hood):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.updatepanel.aspx

Comment: Hi jackson Thanks for your reply.
I am asking about moving between one page to another in my website by clicking on the links in treeview, i want to stop refreshing of masterpage there.
While for retrieving data within my page, i am already using ajax there.
Can i use ajax to stop refreshing on masterpage while moving from one page to another?

Answer (score 0):

The master page class derives from the UserControl class and the master page is like a child control. So we can say that master page is not a true page, when a page loads we can notice  the navigation URL in the address bar is the content page's but not the master page! so we cannot refresh a content page without refreshing master page.

there is one way to avoid flickering the page by adding the code in < Head > section in the masterpage.

```
<meta http-equiv="Page-Enter" content="blendTrans(Duration=0)"/>

<meta http-equiv="Page-Exit" content="blendTrans(Duration=0)"/>
```